# how can I convert a java based annnotation maven project to spring boot?

Tags: maven

how can I convert a java based annotation maven project to spring boot? I do not have xml file, instead I have a used webconfig class and webinitializer class. I know how to convert a xml based project to spring boot. you might think what is the difference? the difference for me is like I said I have used webconfig class and webinitializer, my maven project does not have main class in which one of these classes should I add the @SpringbootApplication,  SpringApplication.run(??.class, args);

Comment: I would suggest to rewrite with Spring Boot from scratch cause Spring Boot has many things which webconfi/webinitalizer has not? (Unfortunately I don't know enough about it)...

Comment: hopefully there a way to fix this issue, without rewritting the whole project in spring boot.

Comment: Ah looks like webinitialzier/webconfig seemed to be already Spring Framework...so then I would say it should be easier ...

Comment: yes, I have used spring mvc maven, but how can I add boot to that? one of the reason I would like to add boot to my project is to add mysql DB, I know it is easier to add a DB to spring Boot application than a  spring mvc maven. maybe there is a way to add DB to spring mvc maven project, but I do not know that.